# Convert to Weka date format

Tags: datetime, weka

I have a csv file with some attributes. One is a date attribute with date in this form - `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` . But Weka takes it as nominal not as date type. How to fix this? Please help me with this. (I use Weka Explorer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A nice reference, you can get it here: https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/formats_and_processing/arff_stable/

It's a simple compilation of attributes from Weka files ...

Example for time:

```
@RELATION Timestamps

@ATTRIBUTE timestamp DATE "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" 

@DATA 
"2001-04-03 12:12:12"
"2001-05-03 12:59:55"
```

Answer (score 2):

on opening the file select or check the invoke mark then a pop up will appear.on the date attribute put the index of the attribute which is a date and on dateFormat put the one similar from csv format then click ok the date will be detected as a date type now

Answer (score 0):

When opening a CSV file in Weka 3.7.0 or later, it is possible specify the attribute(s) that are to have Weka's "date" type:

1. In the Weka Explorer's "Preprocess" tab, click on "Open file ...".
2. In the file selection window that appears, select your CSV file, select "Invoke Options Dialog" (see the image below), then click "Open".

   [image: Weka file selection window]
3. In the window that appears, change the `dateAttributes` and `dateFormat` fields according your data. `dateAttributes` should be the indexes of the attributes that you want to convert to the "date" type, and in your case, `dateFormat` should be `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. Then, click "OK".

   [image: Weka CSVLoader configuration window]
4. At this point, in the Weka Explorer's "Preprocess" tab, you should be able to see that the specified attribute(s) have the "date" type instead of "nominal".

   [image: Weka Explorer's "Preprocess" tab]

---

Similar threads:

- Weka mailing list: [problem in date format in Weka](https://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/problem-in-date-format-in-Weka-td25868.html)
- Pentaho community forums: [how to deal with "a date attribute" in weka?](https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/160812-how-to-deal-with-quot-a-date-attribute-quot-in-weka/)