# How do I convert an attribute to the "date" type when opening a CSV data set in Weka?

Tags: weka

How to use the `ChangeDateFormat` filter in Weka (Waikato Environment for Knowledge Analysis) properly on preprocessing files with a date attribute?

I have the following CSV file:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume
2004-08-19,49.813290,51.835709,47.800831,49.982655,49.982655,44871361
2004-08-20,50.316402,54.336334,50.062355,53.952770,53.952770,22942874
2004-08-23,55.168217,56.528118,54.321388,54.495735,54.495735,18342897
2004-08-24,55.412300,55.591629,51.591621,52.239197,52.239197,15319808
```

... and so on.

When I open it with WEKA, it recognizes the first attribute as "Nominal", not "Date". Then, when I try to apply the `ChangeDateFormat` filter from `filters` → `unsupervised` → `attributes` on the "Date" attribute and click "Apply", Weka gives me an error:

```
Problem filtering instances: Chosen attribute not date.
```

However, there are no filters like "NominalToDate", only the "NominalToBinary" and "NominalToString", and there are no filters like "StringToDate".

Therefore, I had to rename this file to `.arff` and add the `@attribute` headers the following way:

```
@relation GOOG
@attribute Date date 'yyyy-MM-dd'
@attribute Open numeric
@attribute High numeric
@attribute Low numeric
@attribute Close numeric
@attribute AdjClose numeric
@attribute Volume numeric
@data
```

However, I didn't like the idea of manually tinkering the files, so I want to know how to use the `ChangeDateFormat` filter in this case.

How can I use the `ChangeDateFormat` filter to specify the date format of the imported files, and, if it is not possible with the `ChangeDateFormat`, what are the use cases for this filter?

As you see, the datetime in my dataset does not have the time part.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert to Weka date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31058999/convert-to-weka-date-format)

Answer (score 1):

To import a CVS with a date attribute without time, turn on the "Invoke options dialog" checkbox in the "Open file..." dialog.

[image: The Invoke options dialog checkbox in the Weka Open file dialog]

Then, in the "Options" dialog, specify the index of the date attribute and adjust the format accordingly by deleting the time part.

[image: Weka Edit date attribute in the Open file option dialog]

As a result, the date attribute in the imported dataset will have the "Timestamp" type.